# How do I get the filename of an Item?? - Team Foundations SDK

Tags: c#, version-control, tfs

I am trying to get a file by name from TFS. I am getting all the files from a location recursively and then looping through these to find a specific file. It appears that the VersionControl.Client.Item object does not expose the filename (or foldername).

```
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
VersionControlServer vcs = versionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
var allStaticFiles = vcs.GetItems(path + "*", RecursionType.Full).Items;
foreach (var staticFile in allStaticFiles)
{
  if(staticFile == ?? // need the filename)
  {
  }
```

Comment: TFS 2005/2008 or 2010? (2010 works in "slot mode" by default, earlier versions didn't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming TFS2008.)

The type of `vcs.GetItems(...).Items` is [`Item[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.itemset.items%28VS.90%29.aspx).

So therefore `staticFile` is an [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.item%28VS.90%29.aspx) instance.

The properties of `Item` are all server side because details of the path will depend on the client's workspace mapping (there can be multiple workspaces including this item on the same computer for the same user).

You can use [`Item.ServerItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.item.serveritem%28VS.90%29.aspx) to get the filename (take the last path element)

To the path, get a [`Workspace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace%28VS.90%29.aspx) instance representing your current workspace and use one of its methods to map the `ServerItem` to a local path (there are a few with subtly different behaviour, without more context it is not clear which is the right one).

Comment: This is also a solution in TFS2010.